# Polyline bounds for Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-polyline

How can I get this Google map to resize to the bounds of the Polyline bounds?

http://goo.gl/hjOcAx

I think I am correct to use this:

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    decodedPath.getPath().forEach(function(LatLng) {
    bounds.extend(LatLng);
});
map.setBounds(bounds);
```

but I also think I am putting it in the wrong place.

Comment: There is no 'GPolyline.getBounds()' in v3 as there is in v2.  Javascript is not my strong point but I would love to find a solution to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. decodedPath is a path(not a Polyline) and doesn't have a  method `getPath()`.
    use:

   ```
   decodedPath.forEach(function(LatLng) {
      bounds.extend(LatLng);
   });
   ```
2. there is no method `setBounds()`, use `fitBounds()` instead.

Comment: Thank you!  I have also removed the hard-coded lat and lng fields from the myLatlng variable, and removed the 'center' and 'zoom' properties from the myOptions variable, as the fitBounds() method. Works like a charm :)